# Задеплоил на render сервер на джанго, почему-то не видит winkerberos, requirements есть

Tags: django, render

```
  Stored in directory: /opt/render/.cache/wheels/0c/20/6b/a82a18cadf38c2b025ca024798c9ed2ee9f26190aec68153a2
  Building wheel for winkerberos (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for winkerberos (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for winkerberos (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [14 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'winkerberos' extension
      creating build
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/src
      gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/opt/render/project/src/.venv/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.11 -c src/kerberos_sspi.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/src/kerberos_sspi.o
      In file included from src/kerberos_sspi.c:17:
      src/kerberos_sspi.h:21:10: fatal error: Windows.h: No such file or directory
       #include <Windows.h>
                ^~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  **ERROR: Failed building wheel for winkerberos**
Successfully built djongo environ pymongo
Failed to build winkerberos
**ERROR: Could not build wheels for winkerberos, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects**
==> Build failed 
==> Common ways to troubleshoot your deploy: https://docs.render.com/troubleshooting-deploys
```

Comment: Потому что пытаться ставить виндовую библиотеку не на винде это изначально бессмысленная затея

Comment: но у меня винда

Comment: Вы это сервер ?

Comment: а, в этом плане, так и что делать :(

Comment: Очевидно, или использовать сервер с виндой, или не использовать библиотеки которые работают только на винде